# How to order objects by a 'status' variable in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to find a way to display a list of database objects in an order based on their `status` variable. The application is an order tracking app. Each order has a status: 'idle', 'awaiting delivery', 'ready for pickup', etc. I'm wanting to display the list of orders, sorted by their status. I already have a filter that is working, but I'm wondering if there is a way to sort the entire list of orders such that 'idle' orders are on top, followed by 'awaiting delivery' orders, and so on. Obviously, I can't just add `status` to `ordering` in the `admin.py` file, because that sorts statuses alphabetically.

Does anybody know a simple way to fix this issue? I'm sure I'm just over-thinking this whole thing..

Answer (score 1):

All I ended up doing was adding an alpha character to each status name. Since I already had a nice, neat verbose name for each status, I didn't think it affected readability too much. I can't say it's the best solution in the world, but I do believe it is the most simple.

```
   STATUS_OF_ORDER = (
     ('A_IDLE', 'Not yet ordered'),
     ('B_SHIP', 'Awaiting delivery'),
     ('C_PICK', 'Ready for pickup'),
     ('E_UNAV', 'Unavailable for order'),
     ('D_BACK', 'Backordered - awaiting delivery'),
     ('F_CANC', 'Canceled by customer'),
     ('G_ARCH', 'Fulfilled'),
   )
   status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STATUS_OF_ORDER,
                             default='A_IDLE', editable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort in SQL there are two ways to achieve this.

create a model that links your status with numeric value

```
class status (Model.model):
    status = Model.CharField()
    sort_order = Model.IntegerField()
```

you can join this table with your order table and order by sort_order

If this seems not practical to you consider a custom query that does the ordering for you. You can attach this to your orm method with the `.extra` method. See more information about it in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
Order By Case
            When status_order Like 'idle Then 1
            When status_order Like 'awaiting delivery' Then 2
            When status_order Like 'ready for pickup' Then 3
            Else 99
            End Asc
```

Comment: I had thought about using an index like you mention as your first point. However, I didn't want to add anything to my database unless absolutely necessary. I also didn't really follow the second method you mentioned, as I'm still pretty new to Python/Django.

Comment: Well just try it. It won't hurt ;-)